# Datastax Java Driver Using LZ4Factory:JNI

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-boot-maven-plugin, lz4

I have standard spring boot java project in which I am using datastax java driver ( without spring-cassandra) I was trying to enable Lz4 Compression in my driver.
Using application.conf I was able to do so

However when I import and run the program in Intellij It chooses LZ4Factory as JNI ( which is desired)

```
 Lz4Compressor:46 -[]- -[THREAD ID=s0-io-0] [s0] Using LZ4Factory:JNI
```

However when I build jar and run jar with command

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I get different result on same system

```
Lz4Compressor:46 -[]- -[THREAD ID=s0-io-0] [s0] Using LZ4Factory:JavaUnsafe
```